# Find and delete partially duplicate lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, uniq

```
https://www.domain.com/files/G5SPNDOF/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain2.com/dl/G5SPNDOF/JHCGTS/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/ZQWL80BG/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/UCIONEMA/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
```

Given a file with above lines, how do I delete the ones that have duplicate files, but links overall are different, to end up with:

```
https://www.domain.com/files/G5SPNDOF/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
```

Comment: Could you say something about why you decided to keep those two lines in particular and e.g. `https://www.domain2.com/dl/G5SPNDOF/JHCGTS/AAA-1080p.mp4.html` and `https://www.domain.com/files/UCIONEMA/BBB-1080p.mp4.html`?

Comment: @Kusalananda What about the most obvious reason: Those two are the first appearances of the file names?

Comment: @Philippos Sure, I can see that, but it's not clear that this is an absolute requirement or not.

Answer (score 5):

Using awk :

```
awk -F'/' '!seen[$NF]++' file
```

You can also do it using sort. As your file contain a number of fields that change you need to reverse it first :

```
rev file | sort -u -t/ -k1,1 | rev
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any `sed`, you'd choose the lazy "throw all known file names on the hold space" approach:

```
sed 'G;\_/\(.*\)\n.*\1_d;P;s_.*/__;h;d' file
```

- `G` appends the hold space (with all known file names) to the pattern space
- The pattern `/\(.*\)\n.*\1` fits a filename between `/` and the newline, which gets repeated (`\1`) in the collected file names; in this case, `d`elete it, no output, no changes to the hold space
- At this point, we know we found a new word, so `P`rint the line without the appended hold space
- `s_.*/__` removes the path, so the new path list can be copied to the `h`old space. `d` suppresses further output

Answer (score 2):

If your list is huge then to avoid storing all of the file names in memory in awk:

```
$ sort file | awk -F'/' '$NF != prev{print} {prev=$NF}'
https://www.domain.com/files/G5SPNDOF/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/ZQWL80BG/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
```

Otherwise see [@MariusCouet's awk answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720507/133219).

Comment: Are you sure keeping a list of file names in memory can be a bigger problem than `sort`ing such a big file?

Comment: @Philippos yes because `sort` is designed to efficiently handle massive amounts of input by using demand paging, etc. while awk when used as `awk -F'/' '!seen[$NF]++' file` will slow down greatly as the hash array size increases (it's allocated in increasingly larger blocks) before eventually failing when it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.unique(as => *.IO.basename);'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
https://www.domain.com/files/G5SPNDOF/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain2.com/dl/G5SPNDOF/JHCGTS/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/ZQWL80BG/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/UCIONEMA/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
```

Sample Output:

```
https://www.domain.com/files/G5SPNDOF/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
```

Raku understands directory conventions, so you can use `.IO` to convert your string to an IO object, and get the filename with `basename`. Raku's `unique` function is clever enought to take an `as` parameter, so the full file path is returned.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/unique
https://docs.raku.org/routine/IO
https://docs.raku.org/routine/basename
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `datamash` to prefix the original data with the basename (filename at the end) from each URL, and then to group the data by the added column and extract the first URL from each group. The added field is then removed with `cut` at the end of the pipeline. This is reminiscent of how one might do a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```bash
$ datamash basename 1 cut 1 <file | datamash groupby 1 first 2 | cut -f 2
https://www.domain.com/files/G5SPNDOF/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
```

You can instead get the *last* URL from each group:

```bash
$ datamash basename 1 cut 1 <file | datamash -s groupby 1 last 2 | cut -f 2
https://www.domain.com/files/ZQWL80BG/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/UCIONEMA/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
```

... or a random one:

```bash
$ datamash basename 1 cut 1 <file | datamash -s groupby 1 rand 2 | cut -f 2
https://www.domain2.com/dl/G5SPNDOF/JHCGTS/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
$ datamash basename 1 cut 1 <file | datamash -s groupby 1 rand 2 | cut -f 2
https://www.domain.com/files/G5SPNDOF/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/SVSRS0AD/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
$ datamash basename 1 cut 1 <file | datamash -s groupby 1 rand 2 | cut -f 2
https://www.domain.com/files/ZQWL80BG/AAA-1080p.mp4.html
https://www.domain.com/files/UCIONEMA/BBB-1080p.mp4.html
```