# Copy contents of one file to another using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to copy all text from one file into another file using sed on Alma Linux 8. For example, the first file, `old.txt`, is:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5 
...
```

And the other file, `new.txt` is:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

I want to copy entries from `old.txt` into `new.txt` but without any duplicates. Expected output in `new.txt`:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use sed in particular?  Is there something wrong with the other standard tools?

Answer (score 10):

No need for anything except a straightforward sort with a uniqueness constraint.

```
sort -u old.txt new.txt >new.txt.tmp &&
     mv -f new.txt.tmp new.txt
rm -f new.txt.tmp
```

I see that [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) does define the ability for `sort` to [write directly to an input file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/758395/100397), so you could also do this, but I haven't tested to see how robust it is in the event of failure (the previous version guarantees either to keep the original or replace it with the new, without loss):

```
sort -o new.txt -u old.txt new.txt
```

Alternatively you could use `awk`. This version keeps the order of the lines in the files intact, starting with the first file and adding only new lines from subsequent files:

```
awk '
    FNR<NR && h[$0] { next }    # Skip seen lines in secondary files
    { h[$0]=1; print }          # Record the line and output it
' new.txt old.txt
```

I've split this over several lines so I can add comments. Remove those and you could crash it into a single line, but it's generally better to write readable code. It intentionally does not remove duplicate lines already present in the first file, `new.txt`. If you want that,

```
awk '! h[$0]++' new.txt old.txt
```

This increments an associative array value for each line seen, but prints it only if the value was zero (unset).

Comment: Thanks very help full

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the robustness of overwriting input is a trade-off - once it's truncated, you lose the original content.  But on the other hand, it's less likely to fail with `ENOSPC` than the version where input and output have to exist concurrently.

Comment: @TobySpeight if my first solution fails with ENOSPC then the `mv` (rename) will be aborted and the original file left in place. This works because the `rename(2)` syscall is atomic and guarantees either the original or the replacement will be delivered. Given that `sort` uses temporaries in (IIRC) `/var/tmp` I don't think the same can be said if it creates the output file itself from its sorted input

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It's (slightly) more likely to fail, but if it does, it fails in a more recoverable way.

Comment: @Abdullah if one of these answers works best for you please remember to accept it ✓

Answer (score 3):

Based on other answer you can use `sort` command but you can explicitly mention output file and do the sort in place (w/o intermediate file)

```
sort -u -o new.txt old.txt new.txt
```

One of possible `awk` ways:

```
awk -i inplace '{z[$0]=1} END{for( i in z) print i}' new.txt old.txt
```

Be warned that this can "eat" a lot of memory if one or both input files are long. `inplace` will keep the output in `new.txt`

Comment: See also the `-V` option (GNU or compatible) or `sort -nt . -k1,1  -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4` (standard) to sort those quad-decimal IPv4 addresses numerically.

Answer (score 3):

That's not really a job for `sed`, but if you have to use `sed` and your `sed` happens to be GNU `sed`, you could do something like:

```
sed -E '
  :1; $!{N;b1}
  :2; s/^((.*)$(.|\n)*)\n\2$/\1/m; t2
  ' new.txt old.txt
```

Where:

- `:1; $!{N;b1}` loads the whole input (both files in the pattern space) in a loop.
- `:2; s/^((.*)$(.|\n)*)\n\1$/\1/m; t2` removes duplicated lines in that pattern space in a loop.

To modify `new.txt` in-place, you could do:

```
sed -nE '
  :1; $!{N;b1}
  :2; s/^((.*)$(.|\n)*)\n\1$/\1/m; t2
  w new.txt
  ' new.txt old.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
grep -vFxf new.txt old.txt >> new.txt
```

The `-v` flag tells `grep` to print lines that do NOT match the pattern given, and the `-f new.txt` tells `grep` to use the lines in the file `new.txt` as the patterns to search for. With `-F`, the  *patterns* are `F`ixed strings instead of basic regular expressions and with `-x`, they have to match the full lines. So `grep -vFxf new.txt old.txt` means "show me all lines in `old.txt` that are missing from `new.txt`".

We append those lines to `new.txt` using the `>>` redirection operator. Note that `new.txt` is used here both  as input and  as output, but `grep` will read the full initial contents of `new.txt` to build the list of strings to search and stop reading it after that, so extra lines printed afterwards to `new.txt` won't be read again.

Comment: @stéphane thanks. Um. I have absolutely no idea why I used `tee -a` instead of the obvious `>>`. The only thing I can think of is that I have only had one coffee today...

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.unique;'  old.txt new.txt  > tmp.txt
```

Raku will read files off the commandline using the workhorse `lines` routine. So two files can be read-in, and `>` redirected into a `tmp.txt` file. Then once you verify your result, you can copy the `tmp.txt` file back over `new.txt`.

Raku does not do "in-place" editing (i.e. there's no Raku equivalent of Perl's `-i` command line flag).

Sample Input `old.txt`:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
```

Sample Input `new.txt`:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

Sample Output `tmp.txt`:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
```

A nice aspect of Raku's `unique` routine is that it takes an `as` parameter, meaning that only a portion of the input line gets used in the `unique` comparison. Such an option allows (for example), recovery of unique file names from complete paths, discarding duplicate names in different directories. See the first SO link below for details.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720574/227738
https://docs.raku.org/routine/unique
https://raku.org

Comment: I'll edit my answer.