# Is there a command that makes another command "in-place"?

Tags: shell, files, pipe, coreutils

I find myself trying to "edit" a file in-place quite a lot in my shell. Say, I want to remove all lines in `words.txt` that contain the letter *e*. Then, I would execute:

```
$ grep -v e words.txt > words-without-e.txt
$ mv words-without-e.txt words.txt
```

Many people are confused why they are left with an empty file when executing the following (I am not):

```
$ grep -v e words.txt > words.txt
grep: words.txt: input file is also the output
```

Some commands have special flags for in-place behaviour, like `--in-place` (see [`sed(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)) to allow this. It's possible to use [`sponge(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge), but this requires me to type the file name twice, which I don't like.

```
$ grep -v e words.txt | sponge words.txt
```

I have defined a function that I find handy:

```
function inplace { "${@:2}" < "$1" | sponge $1 }
```

With it, I can now do:

```
$ inplace words.txt grep -v e
```

I know that this is limited to "stream processing", i.e. commands that take standard input, process it, and produce standard output. But many commands do.

Maybe I looked in the wrong places, but I haven't stumbled across a similar definition yet, especially given how often the question about in-place editing comes up.

- Is there a common utility that serves the same purpose?
- Have you defined such a function? How does your definition look like? What did you call it?
- Why does this not come up more often? Or did I just miss it?

Comment: In a way, it's odd that `sponge` itself doesn't provide the wrapper functionality... But it's also impossible to make a really generic wrapper, because an arbitrary tool might edit the given file in-place itself, and not print to stdout. Using the wrapper with one like that might be problematic. Also there's the question of caching the data to memory vs. to a temporary file, and overwriting the target in-place vs. creating a new file with the same name... (not sure what sponge does)

Comment: Anyway, quote the expansions so that your function works with arbitrary filenames: `inplace() { "${@:2}" < "$1" | sponge "$1" }`

Comment: Related, first solution in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/758394/100397)

Comment: @ilkkachu, rather `inplace() { "${@:2}" < "$1" | sponge -- "$1"; }` to deal with arbitrary file  paths. Or `inplace() (file="${1?}"; shift; <"$file" "$@" | sponge -- "$file")` to avoid that ksh93ism. Setting the `pipefail` option in there would also be useful to report failure of the command (in any case, the file is lost if the command fails).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yes, indeed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a generic utility that can make any command work in-place.

Usually, when people want to programatically edit files in-place, they use `sed` or `perl` with `-i` parameter.

Probably that's the reason why this topic does not come up often - contrary to what you may think, it is not so much needed if there are utilities that can edit files in-place.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the `-i` flags. Will edit the question.